# Devise with user logged in using multiple scopes logs all but one out when using token_authenticateable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I'm using Devise with multiple scopes (in this case, a user scope and an admin scope) and admins are able to 'become' a user using the [approach on the Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin). This works well, except that I have one particular page that requires the use of an auth token that causes a problem with a session logged in under both a user and admin scope. The page generates a POST to a controller that requires a user to be logged in using the user auth token. The POST succeeds, but afterwards, the admin scope has been signed out. (Meaning that admin_signed_in? returns false.) Other pages that execute POSTs to the same controller without requiring the auth token work as expected without logging out the admin scope.

I suspect that something is going on with token_authenticatable where the authentication of any scopes other than the one associated with that specific token are logged out. I've searched for references in the devise gem source to both the devise sign_out and warden logout methods that could be invoked as part of the token_authenticatable functionality and wasn't able to find anything.

This is happening with Devise 1.3.4. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think I found a way to work around this problem. I added a before_filter in the affected controller before the before_filter for authenticate_user. The new before_filter checks to see if an admin is logged in (admin_signed_in? == true) and if so, stores the admin user ID. I then added an after_filter that checks to see if an admin user ID has been stored and if so, calls sign_in(:admin, Admin.find(@admin_id)).

It feels a little hack-y, but best I could come up with so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for a solution to this, I found that the before_filter/after_filter approach I described in the comment to my question seems to work fine. I think that a better, more general solution to this would be to make a change to the devise gem and underlying calls to warden, but didn't have time to make those changes for this particular problem yet.